# Representing a "ask to answer" feature on Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

The "ask to answer" feature on quora is a similar technical issue to the one i am facing.

Essentially, one user(suggester) asks another user(suggested) to answer a question(question).

What would be the best way to represent this schema in mongodb?

I thought about having something like this:

```
User class stores an array called suggested questions, which stores a pair of values
Each value is "suggester_userid | question_id"
```

This would be efficient from a retrieval pov, but seems to break proper schema design.

What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: I think **@dm** has the correct answer here, but I want to clarify that MongoDB *"proper schema design"* it not a clear concept with MongoDB. There are lots of "correct" ways to model the same data based entirely on what queries you're looking to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Essentially, one user(suggester) asks
>   another user(suggested) to answer a
>   question(question).

not sure i understand the problem but a collection

```
{ suggester:..., suggested:..., question:...}
```

might be fine -- suggester and suggested can be indexed.

Comment: this would essentially be similar to the "sql way" , where you represent the relationships in a separate table

Answer (score 1):

I have similar schema in my app, i have used different collection called suggestion

it looks likee this (Ruby mongoid class)

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paranoia

  field :Suggested_id, :type => BSON::ObjectId
  field :Question_id, :type => BSON::ObjectId

  embedded_in :user
end
```

this will ultimately translated to

```
User
 |
  _  Name
  _  Other fields
  _  Suggestions (embedded doc)
        - Suggested_id
        - Question_id
```

If you think the suggestion limit may exceeds the mongo doc size, then you can change the embedded doc to [DbRef document](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References), so the each user doc will have one associated suggestion documents. so the single suggestion document will have the user_id and all the suggestions made by the user as a embedded docs (items)

```
 Suggestion
   |
    _ user_id
    _ items
        |
          _ suggested_id
          _ Questionid
        |
          _ suggested_id
          _ Questionid
```

Hope this helps